# What is the gas refund for clearing out storage via SSTORE?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, gas, gas-refund

There is a lot of conflicting information due to the change in the gas refund mechanism from [EIP-3298](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3298).

According to [evm.codes](https://www.evm.codes/#55) the user will still be charged net 200 gas for clearing out a storage slot.

Since I did not see a recent post I wanted to confirm all of this information is correct and current.

Comment: I won't check the details, but evm.codes seems to match go-ethereum implementation https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.10.23/core/vm/gas_table.go#L96.

Answer (score 0):

From the EIP-3298 you shared, we can see the status is "Stagnant", meaning the EIP has been in Draft or Review state, or inactive for a period of 6 months.

But I found a variant of this EIP which has been proposed 2 months later :[EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529)

> Remove gas refunds for SELFDESTRUCT, and reduce gas refunds for SSTORE to a lower level

This one is Final and has been implemented in the London Upgrade (which is also the upgrade where EIP-1559 as been implemented) [as you can see here](https://ethereum.org/en/history/#london) on ethereum.org